# Outputting JSON logs on Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

Recently we upgraded our EB environments from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2. After the upgrade, we see the log format has changed. All logs now have something prefix like this `Apr 30 20:36:39 ip-172-31-2-140 web:` . So when we write a JSON log, the fields cannot be parsed by Log Insights easily. How can we get rid of this prefix?

Comment: There are some options to accomplish this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1017974/outputting-json-logs-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-amazon-linux-2